# Websphere Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, character-encoding, websphere, url-encoding

I'm getting

**`Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /xyz/?????.pdf`** while hitting url **`localhost:9080/xyz/液压无极限.pdf`**.
But when I hit **`localhost:9080/xyz/abc.pdf`** I got the pdf downloaded.

I am using websphere 8.5.5.

Os - IBM AIX

I have already tried setting

> JVM option -Dclient.encoding.override = UTF-8

Comment: take a look here maybe it helps... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with Websphere but with OS(AIX) on which Webshere is installed. It is because of **locale** in AIX. By default

## locale

```
LANG=C  
LC_COLLATE="C"  
LC_CTYPE="C"  
LC_MONETARY="C"  
LC_NUMERIC="C"  
LC_TIME="C"  
LC_MESSAGES="C"  
LC_ALL=
```

The above output indicates that the system locale "C" is currently being used.
The 'C' locale is set as "default" locale for applications,which means that their strings are displayed as written in the initial code (without passing through a translation lookup).

To get translation lookup u need to set locale to EN_US.UTF-8(For ref. [Click here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/luit.htm))

## locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"    
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"        
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"     
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the WebContainer custom property "DecodeUrlAsUTF8" to true.

For documentation on how to set WebContainer custom properties see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-18-6-1196&lang=en